# View dont refresh when add a new json object in array. REACT NATIVE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, barcode-scanner

the program compiles perfect, but when I scan a product, it doesn't refresh in the view.
I have mounted a mysql xampp with all the products. when querying a barcode. I get in response the detail of the product, and, add the json response with parse object in a array.

the view refresh when click TouchableOpacity, later of scan a product.

```html
import React, {Component, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Dimensions,Image, View, Text,AsyncStorage, TouchableOpacity, Grid, StyleSheet, ScrollView,ToastAndroid} from 'react-native';
import { SearchBar, Card, Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
import { BarCodeScanner } from 'expo-barcode-scanner';
//import { NumberList } from './NumberList';
const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');
const urlApi = "http://192.168.1.24/rst/api/getProduct.php";
const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
class SaleScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      scan: false,
      result: null,
      ScanResult: false,
      hasPermission: true,
      setHasPermission: true,
      productos: [],
      jwt: null,
    };
    //this.componentDidMount();
  }

  async componentDidMount(){
    let _jwt = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
    this.setState({
      jwt: _jwt
    });
  }
  
  _searchProduct = async (data) =>  {

      try {
        let response = await fetch(urlApi,{
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization:  'Bearer '+this.state.jwt
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            CodiBarra: data
          })
        });
        let responseJson = await response.json();
        //console.log(responseJson);
        if (responseJson.codibarra === null) {
          //console.log("retorna falso");
          return false;
        }
        else
        {
          if(this.state.productos != null)
          {
            this.state.productos.push(responseJson[0]);
            //this.setState({productos: this.state.productos.push(responseJson[0])})
            //console.log(this.state.productos);
          }
          else
          {
            this.state.productos.push(responseJson[0]);
          }
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
  };

  render(){
    const { scan, ScanResult, result, hasPermission, setHasPermission, productos } = this.state;
    const activeBarcode = ()=> {
        this.setState({
          scan: true
      })
    }
    const handleBarCodeScanned = async ({ type, data }) => {
      //console.log('scanned data' + data);
      this.setState({result: data, scan: false, ScanResult: false});
      this._searchProduct(data);
    };

    if (hasPermission === null) {
      return <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text>;
    }
    if (hasPermission === false) {
      return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
    }
    return (
      <View style= {{flex: 1}}>
        {productos.length == 0 &&
          <View style = {styles.button}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress= {activeBarcode}
            style={{
                borderWidth:1,
                borderColor:'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
                alignItems:'center',
                justifyContent:'center',
                width:50,
                height:50,
                backgroundColor:'#fff',
                borderRadius:50,
                position: 'absolute',
                marginTop: 10,
                marginLeft: width - 100
                }}
            >
                <Icon
                  type="font-awesome"
                  name="barcode"
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        }
        {productos.length>0 && 
          <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <View style = {styles.button}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress= {activeBarcode}
                  style={{
                      borderWidth:1,
                      borderColor:'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
                      alignItems:'center',
                      justifyContent:'center',
                      width:50,
                      height:50,
                      backgroundColor:'#fff',
                      borderRadius:50,
                      position: 'absolute',
                      marginTop: 10,
                      marginLeft: width - 100
                      }}
                >
                  <Icon
                    type="font-awesome"
                    name="barcode"
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style ={{flex:1,marginTop:20}}>
              <ScrollView>
                <NumberList products={this.state.productos} />
              </ScrollView>
            </View>
            <View style ={{flex:1,marginTop:20}}>
              <View style={{flexDirection:"row", height: 50, width: width, backgroundColor: "green", justifyContent: "center",}}>
                <View style = {{ flexDirection:"column"}}>
                  <Text style = {{ fontSize: 40,color:"white"}}>{"TOTAL: "}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{justifyContent: "center", flexDirection:"row-reverse", paddingRight:20}}>
                  <Text style = {{ fontSize: 40,color:"white"}}>{result.precioventa}</Text>
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        }
        {scan &&
            <BarCodeScanner
              onBarCodeScanned={handleBarCodeScanned}
              style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
            />
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
}

function NumberList(props) {
  console.log("NUMBERLIST")
  console.log(props);
  const products = props.products;
  const listItems = products.map((product) =>
    // Correct! Key should be specified inside the array.
    <ListItem key={product.key}              value={product} />  
  );

  return (
    <View>
      {listItems}
    </View>
  );
}


function ListItem(props) {
  // Correct! There is no need to specify the key here:
  const u = props.value;
  return (
        <View>
          {u &&
            <Card>
              <View style={{flexDirection:"row"}}>
                <Icon
                  name = "monetization-on"
                  size = {40}
                />
                <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: "column", paddingTop: 10}}><Text>{u.descripcion}</Text></View>
                <View style = {{flexDirection:"row-reverse", paddingTop: 10}}><Text>{u.precioventa}</Text></View>
              </View>
            </Card>
          }
        </View>);
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      backgroundColor: 'black'
    },
    containerHome:{
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      height: height,
      width: width,
      flexDirection: 'column'
    },
    cardSales:{
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      flex: 1,
      padding: 15,
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderRadius: 10,
      borderColor: '#ddd',
      borderBottomWidth: 7,
      //shadowColor: '#000',
      shadowColor: "#191919",
      shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
      shadowOpacity: 0.8,
      shadowRadius: 2,
      elevation: 1,
      marginLeft: 5,
      marginRight: 5,
      marginTop: 20,
    },
    cardContent:{
      flexDirection: 'row-reverse',
      fontSize: 50
    },
    button:{
      flexDirection: 'column',
      marginTop: 20,
      marginLeft: 20,
      marginRight: 20,
    },
    contentActionFast:{
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      flexDirection: 'row',
      alignItems:'center',
      justifyContent: 'space-between',
      flex:1
    }
  });

export default SaleScreen;
```

if anyone could help me I'd really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component isn't re-rendering because in `_searchProduct` you're doing `this.state.productos.push(responseJson[0]);` to update the state object when you should be using `setState()`. Directly modifying the state, which you're doing now, won't trigger a re-render and could lead to other problems, which is why you should never do it and always use `setState()` (or a hook) to update state. This is mentioned in the docs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly.

Instead try:

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
    productos: [...prevState.productos, responseJson[0]]
});
```